# json_encode not working for a nested array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to return results from 2 queries as json. `var_dump($data)` works but can't `json_encode` returns empty/ not working.

```
$data = array();

$array_articles = array();
$sql_articles = $mysqli->query("select something something");
while ( $article = $sql_articles->fetch_assoc() ){
  $array_articles[] = $article;
}

$array_posts = array();
$sql_posts = $mysqli->query("select something something");
while ( $post = $sql_posts->fetch_assoc() ){
  $array_posts[] = $post;
}

$data = array(
  'top_articles' => $array_articles,
  'top_posts' => $array_posts
);

echo json_encode( $data );
```

Comment: Please paste the var_dump($data) and var_dump(json_encode($data)) in the post.

Comment: What does `json_last_error()` or `json_last_error_msg()`, called after the failed `json_encode()` return?

Comment: @Aashishgaba it also returns blank.

Comment: @Martin it returns message `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.`

Comment: please note that using capital letters as you have done in the title is equivalent to shouting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the things you put in json_encode must be UTF8. I think some of the content is not UTF-8 encoded.

You can add [extra parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) to json_encode.

You could give it a try like this:
`echo json_encode($data, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE | JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR)`